# Match string between /word to the last slash

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to match string using Regex between /one and to the latest slash.
So for example:

```
https://someurl/one/two/three.pdf -> should return one/two
https://someurl/one/two/three/four.pdf -> should return one/two/three
https://someurl/one/two/three/four/five.pdf -> should return one/two/three/four
```

I tried something with

```
\b(\/dat)\B.*?(?:.)*
```

Comment: There is no `dat` present. This will match it `https?://someurl/(\S+)/` https://regex101.com/r/9IRnNL/1

Comment: You probably want `/(one/.*)/` like [shown here](https://regex101.com/r/W6LDmY/2).

Comment: Or the combination of those `https?://[^/]*/(one/\S+)/`  https://regex101.com/r/5QazGm/1

Comment: In C#, you do not need to escape forward slashes in the regex patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I interpret your question correctly, but try:

```
^https:\/\/.*?\/(.*)\/
```

Where you can referce capture group one for your matched result. See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CWeyay/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `https:\/\/` - Match "https//" literally.
- `.*?\/` - Lazy match of 0+ characters other than newline upto the next literal forward slash.
- `(.*)` - A 1st capture group holding a greedy match of 0+ characters other than newline upto;
- `\/` - The last used literal forward slash.

Comment: It works using ^https://.?/(.)/ but I have a problem when I test it using c#. It seems like it using ECMAScript. It matches the string from the beginning.

Comment: @mskuratowski, not sure what you mean with "*It matches the string from the beginning.*". Just reference the 1st capture group.

Comment: I mean it doesn't work expected if I switch to ECMA flavor

Comment: @mskuratowski, see the comment below your question stating that with "C#", there is no need to escape forward slashes. Does that solve the issue?